# PHPStorm REST Client - Basic Authentication

Tags: rest, authentication, phpstorm

I have written my own API which requires basic authentication, such as:

```
user:james
pass:1111
```

I can call resources using urls such as:

http://api.james.com/myapi/orders/get

I wish to be able to use the REST client in PHPStorm but I cannot work out how to send my authentication details. Does anyone know how to do this? Do you have to setup a Proxy server, or can you pass the authentication somehow in the URI above?

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

James

Comment: HTTP Authentication headers are supported by REST Client (PhpStorm **v7**) -- http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7176

Answer (score 2):

For usage Basic Auth you will need send header 'Authorization', for example:

> Authorization: Basic amFuc29uQG1haWwucnU6MTIzNDU2

Value of this header you can get from debug console of your browser (firebug in FireFox or developer tools in Chrome). Start GET request from your browser, when you will need authorize - do it. Than open debug console 'network' tab and try this request one more time.
Now you will find in headers new one 'Authorization', that formed by browser when you was authorized.

Just copy content of this header and use it in PhpStorm REST-client.

Comment: There is no real need in such steps -- REST client in upcoming **v7** has special "helper" where you just enter user name and password and it will build proper Authorization header for you (the already mentioned [WI-7176](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7176) ticket). But for v6 this answer is fine.

Comment: I'm looking forward to v7 coming then as this will make the REST client very useful. until then I will try Janson's suggestion - thanks everyone.

Comment: You can try it even now (I'm using EAP builds on regular basis) -- it can be run in parallel to your current version (IDE-wide settings are stored in separate folders).